# How to make of responsive design in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, design-patterns

## Code

App.js

```
<View style={style.headr}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
    >
      <Image style={style.backimg} source={require("../img/back.png")} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Text style={{ fontSize: 23, marginLeft: deviceWidth/5, color: '#fff' ,}}>Notification</Text>
</View>
```

css

```
headr: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#3C79F5',
    elevation: 2,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomRightRadius:50
},
```

here is img

[image]

I want Img 1 output but when i try to is look like Img2 output

how to do full responsiv output like img1

Comment: looks like the images are missing?

Comment: no img is here [here is img enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-dimensions

This is awesome library for responsive ui in react native for both mobile and tab screen sizes. Install via nom or yarn
And the use case is simple

It's offers responsive width , height and font size where 1 is equal to 1%  and 10 equals 10% and 100 equal 100% of screen. And you can make single code to work for every mobile or tab device.

It's simply Divide your ui in percentage Basis and make it look responsive

```
import { View } from "react-native";
import {
  useResponsiveHeight,
  useResponsiveWidth
} from "react-native-responsive-dimensions";
 
const App = () => {
  const height = useResponsiveHeight(25);
  const width = useResponsiveWidth(25);
 
  return <View style={{ height, width }} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For responsive height , width , margin , padding .. you can use this npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-screen

For responsive font size , you can go with this npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-fontsize

Regarding design issue you are facing , we can only inform after you put all code that you did

As you added code for style of `headr` then it looks like `borderBottomLeftRadius` pending to curv from bottom left side same as right one to match expect result

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: @Gattu can you please share more details about what exactly not working so i can guide according to that

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@gattu/viewstyle here is code